# JSP, Java, Spring, iterating through HashMap and calling basic getter method from its value?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I'm a bit lost on how to do this properly, I am sending a variable to my model in Spring that is like this:

```
Map<Integer, Tab2WorkTableDocumentCounts> finalJspList = new HashMap<Integer, Tab2WorkTableDocumentCounts>();
```

Where `Tab2WorkTableDocumentCounts` is a simple object like this (with getters and setters)

```
public class Tab2WorkTableDocumentCounts {

private Integer countTier1;
private Integer countTier2;
private Integer countTier3;
private Integer countTier4;
private Integer countTier5;
}
```

So finalJspList is a hashmap containing a series of objects with a getter method that I am trying to call. I am trying like below but its giving a syntax error in the IDE. I want to call the method like `getCountTier1()` for each `entry.value` in the hashmap and display it as HTML

Any advice to help me clear this up would be appreciated.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>


<c:forEach items="${finalJspList}" var="finalJspList">

                    <ul class="cust">
                      <li class="cust-name">${entry.key}</li>
                      <li class="lvl-1">${fn:entry.value().getCountTier1()}</li>
                      <li class="lvl-2 completed">${fn:entry.value().getCountTier2()}</li>
                      <li class="lvl-3">${fn:entry.value().getCountTier3()}</li>
                      <li class="lvl-4">${fn:entry.value().getCountTier4()}</li>
                      <li class="lvl-5">${fn:entry.value().getCountTier5()}</li>
                      <li class="export"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.liquisdesign.com/stage/jfit/images/export-icon.png" width="20px"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </c:forEach>
```

Comment: If there's an error, then show us the error, don't leave us guessing.

Comment: Its an IDE syntax error: `Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - The function fn:entry is undefined
 - The method getValue() is undefined for the type 
  String`

Comment: What were you expecting `entry` to refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- access them by property names, not getters - `${entry.value.countTier1}`
- set `var="entry"` (instead of `finalJspList`)
- get rid of `fn:`

Technically, getters would work with the latest version of EL, but the code looks cleaner if you just use the property names.

Answer (score 0):

did `<c:out value="${finalJspList.countTier1}" escapeXml="false"/>` not work?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this was what you meant:

```
<c:forEach items="${finalJspList}" var="entry">

                <ul class="cust">
                  <li class="cust-name">${entry.key}</li>
                  <li class="lvl-1">${entry.value.countTier1}</li>
                  <li class="lvl-2 completed">${entry.value.countTier2}</li>
                  <li class="lvl-3">${entry.value.countTier3}</li>
                  <li class="lvl-4">${entry.value.countTier4}</li>
                  <li class="lvl-5">${entry.value.countTier5}</li>
                  <li class="export"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.liquisdesign.com/stage/jfit/images/export-icon.png" width="20px"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </c:forEach>
```

You weren't declaring the `entry` variable anywhere, you need to do that in the `foreach`. Also, you shouldn't call methods in JSTL, you should refer to property names, as above.